# How to output instance of DC2Type:array

Tags: doctrine, twig, symfony4

In my table column i have 2 formats data:

A version) incorrect format records in table (column: mylinks > longtext > DC2Type:array) - approximately 1330 records:

```
a:4:{s:7:"content";s:11:"link 1 name";s:3:"url";s:17:"https://link1.com";i:2;s:11:"link 2 name";i:3;s:17:"https://link2.com";}
```

B version) correct format records in table (column: mylinks > longtext > DC2Type:array) - approximately 3200 records:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:11:"link 1 name";i:1;s:17:"https://link1.com";i:2;s:11:"link 2 name";i:3;s:17:"https://link2.com";}
```

And in my twig file i read this as:

```
{% if requirement.mylinks|length == 2 %}
    - <a href="{{ requirement.mylinks|last }}" target="_blank">{{ requirement.mylinks|first|raw }}</a>
{% elseif requirement.mylinks|length == 4 %}
    - <a href="{{ requirement.mylinks[1] }}" target="_blank">{{ requirement.mylinks|first|raw }}</a><br /><br />
    - <a href="{{ requirement.mylinks|last }}" target="_blank">{{ requirement.mylinks[2]|raw }}</a>
{% elseif requirement.mylinks|length == 6 %}
    - <a href="{{ requirement.mylinks[1] }}" target="_blank">{{ requirement.mylinks|first|raw }}</a><br /><br />
    - <a href="{{ requirement.mylinks[3] }}" target="_blank">{{ requirement.mylinks[2]|raw }}</a><br /><br />
    - <a href="{{ requirement.mylinks|last }}" target="_blank">{{ requirement.mylinks[4]|raw }}</a>
{% endif %}
```

Of course when if transform my B version data then everything is ok. But when if transform my A version data then it dont work and dont display correctly links.

My question is:

Is it possible to read the A version data correctly in this situation only using Twig (while still displaying the B version)? If not, what are my options?

If I have to read incorrect data formats in PHP, what is the best way to do it so that I can later easily display both data formats in Twig?

I will be grateful for constructive help

Comment: That looks like serialized data to me, why don't you unserialize the data first and maybe wrap them in a wrapper class, so that you only have to worry about passing one type of variable to your template. FWIW: twig should be used to *display* data, not transform/alter it.  "*what is the best way to do*" - Asking for the best way will only lead to opinionated answer, making your question off-topic.